# android native method not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

i get No implementation found for native Lcom/vb/HAR/VBHARActivity;.nativeMain:()V error on windows 7. i have compiled and run sanangeles and hello-jni samples with no problem on emulator and device. here are the specs
window 7, ndk-9rb, adt 22(comes with eclipse), java 1.7, mingw, no cygwin, ndk-build and android project build gives no errors. the android project has minimum sdk of 10 and target 19. libvbhar.so is 29k in the libs directory but much larger in obj directory. verified that the shared lib is copied to emulator.

the paths for the project are
src\com\vb\HAR\VBHARActivity.java

```
public class VBHARActivity extends Activity {
    static {System.loadLibrary("vbhar");}
    public static native void nativeMain();
    private Button btn; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vbhar);
        this.btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Log.i("", "vb_har before button");      
        this.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("", "vb_har calling native c code");
                nativeMain();
            }
          });

    }
}
```

## c code

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "HARCVB.h"
void Java_com_vb_vbHarC_VBHARActivity_nativeMain(JNIEnv*  env)
{
    maincall();
}
```

## android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK --std=c99
LOCAL_MODULE    := vbhar
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HARCVB.cpp \
 vbMain.c \
 vbHarApp.c \
 vbHarUtil.c \
 vbSensorData.c \
 vbSupport.c \
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

thank you for your help
alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for `Java_com_vb_HAR_VBHARActivity_nativeMain`, but you're providing `Java_com_vb_vbHarC_VBHARActivity_nativeMain`.  Rename your method to match.

You should also make sure that it's declared with `extern "C"`.

Comment: com/vb/HAR/ was different from the package name.